# Como alternar o símbolo #(cerquilha) pelo $(cifrão) no terminal após trocar usuário

Tags: linux, variáveis, script, shell, terminal

Vou ser direto, pois o Título denota parte da minha curiosidade sobre o console linux.

## Explico

Em algumas distros tipo - **xPud** e **Basiclinux3** não tem suporte "HOME" é só "ROOT" e pronto!

Na distro que estou usando, o cabeçalho "#" no *console* não muda para "$" após logar.

## Dúvida

Não sei como funciona isso e/ou simplesmente como isso deve ser feito. Alguém sabe!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] como funciona isso [...] como isso deve ser feito [...]

## Solucionei desta forma:

Baixei o pacote *passwd.tgz* do **slackware-0.4**

Este contém o "*getty*" que é o segundo dos três programas (init, getty e login) usados pelo sistema para permitir o acesso dos usuários.

Até então, a distro em uso, fora construído minimalista tendo como base deste pacote só `init`

Feito isso, tive de criar dois novos arquivos no diretório `/etc`, são eles:

**group** 

**passwd**

Para o arquivo "*group*" escrevi assim:

`root::0:root,lx`

Já no "*passwd*", fiz:

`root::0:0::/root:/bin/sh`

`lx::1001:1001::/home/lx:/bin/sh`

> Este trabalho rendoso, foi preciso porque nem todas as distros disponíveis na web, vem completa, apresentam-se de maneira sobre um único *usuário* o "*root*".

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo `/etc/profile` geralmente possui uma variável chamada `PS1` (pode-se encontrá-la digitando `echo $PS1`), ela possui a função de criar uma mascara para a entrada do *Bash*, fazendo a alteração do seu valor, altera o escrito em seu terminal.

```
export PS1='\u@\h \w $ '
# \u mostra o nome do usuário
# \h mostra o host do usuário (nome da maquina)
# \w ou \W mostra o path, para W pasta atual e w caminho absoluto
# para colorir a saída, basta usar '\[\033[01;34m\]' para colorir com verde e negrito.
```

Para aplicar a todos os usuários, basta redefinir a variável em `/etc/profile`

```
export PS1='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
```